Slots don't work as nested conditional component
I'm working with Quasar/Vue 3. Imagine a scenerio.

IndexPage.vue - page subjected to routes
AwPage.vue    - wrapper component, suppose to have slots, used in IndexPage
_sub/PageDesktop PageDesktop PageDesktopall have have 3 slots.
each page is then imported into AwPage.vue, on the base condition each will be rendered.

All in one - Structure
**Summing up, the result is slotted content doesn't load. **
Result, It suppose to have content
What I tried

I removed markRaw and shallowRef, assuming they could be potential blockers.
I removed <component :is="Pages[variant]" />
To test I just added PageDesktop, single component, no conditional, but It had the same blank screen on the browser. Screenshots I've already shared.

IndexPage.vue
<template>
  <AwPage variant="desktop">
    <template #sidebar>
      <AwSidebar :tags="tagsData" />
    </template>

    <template #list>
      <!-- <NotesList :notes="notesData" /> -->
      <NotesList :notes="notesData" />
    </template>

    <template #editor>
      <template v-if="!!$route.query.mode">
        <AwNoteEditor v-if="$route.query.mode === 'edit'" :notes="notesData" />
        <AwNoteView v-if="$route.query.mode === 'view'" :notes="notesData" />
      </template>
      <div v-else>
        <AwSelectNote />
      </div>
    </template>
  </AwPage>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import AwPage from 'src/components/shared/AwPage/AwPage.vue';

const tagsData = tags;
const notesData = notes;
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>


AwPage.vue
<!-- eslint-disable vue/multi-word-component-names -->
<script setup lang="ts">
// import PageDesktop from './sub/PageDesktop.vue';
// import PageMobile from './sub/PageMobile.vue';
// import PageTablet from './sub/PageTablet.vue';

defineProps<{
  debug?: boolean;
  variant: 'desktop' | 'tablet' | 'mobile';
}>();

// const Pages = shallowRef({
//   desktop: PageDesktop,
//   tablet: PageTablet,
//   mobile: PageMobile,
// });

// console.log(Pages);
//
</script>

<template>
  <!-- <component :is="PageDesktop" :debug="debug" /> -->
  <PageDesktop />
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .responsive-section {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .q-drawer {
    display: block;
  }
  .note-view {
    display: none;
  }
  .note-list {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .side {
    width: 35.15%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  .list {
    width: 64.85%;
  }
  .list-name {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>


PageDesktop
<template>
  <q-page class="row justify-between">
    <section class="row justify-between t-w-[45%]">
      <aside class="t-w-[46.15%] side" :class="{ 'border-debug': debug }">
        <slot name="sidebar" />
      </aside>
      <div class="t-w-[53.85%] bg-dark" :class="{ 'border-debug': debug }">
        <slot name="list" />
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="t-w-[54.86%]" :class="{ 'border-debug': debug }">
      <slot name="editor" />
    </section>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  debug?: boolean;
}>();
</script>


TL;DR
All I need to make UI responsive on the base of prop. Already 3 pages with relevant size CSS is created, I just pass prop and want to render different layout on different screen size.
Possible problem
As I thing it's not something wrong with slots. The main problem is AwPage expects slots immediately but I have added conditional rendering. I called PageDesktop on IndexPage.vue instead of AwPage. It worked but this's not what I need.
<template>
  <PageDesktop variant="desktop">
    <template #sidebar>
      <AwSidebar :tags="tagsData" />
    </template>

    <template #list>
      <!-- <NotesList :notes="notesData" /> -->
      <NotesList :notes="notesData" />
    </template>

    <template #editor>
      <template v-if="!!$route.query.mode">
        <AwNoteEditor v-if="$route.query.mode === 'edit'" :notes="notesData" />
        <AwNoteView v-if="$route.query.mode === 'view'" :notes="notesData" />
      </template>
      <div v-else>
        <AwSelectNote />
      </div>
    </template>
  </PageDesktop>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// import AwPage from 'src/components/shared/AwPage/AwPage.vue';

const tagsData = tags;
const notesData = notes;
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>


Why is import PageDesktop commented? This is the obvious reason for it to not be rendered

@EstusFlask I've used vite unplugin-components. This is not the actual problem.

The question should have contained this info, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's impossible to say what's the actual problem without knowing the details. Basically what you try to do should work, if you render a component, it should be rendered, the rest depends on anything that could go wrong on your side. Unplugin itself is a magical tool that works in undetermined ways and provides an additional point of failure. Can you use explicit imports to eliminate it? You can start debugging with checking the output html layout AND comp hierarchy in vue devtools
